# UISlider setValue "Leaking"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

Hey  hope someone can help as I am at my wits end with this!?

I have a UISlider. I would like it to move as progress of a task takes place (playing music).

Im setting its value as the continues events happen. (progress through the track)

```
-(void)updateSlider:(float)value {
    NSLog(@" %f ",value);
    [timeIndexSlider setValue: value animated:YES];
}
```

Logs state that the float value is fine..

but its just doesn't move and I get the no autorelease pool - just leaking message, that you would get from a thread without one in the console. There is no thread involved on my part.

Is there a problem updating a UISlider this often?

Is there another way of controlling the sliders movement?

Cheers

Comment: From where do you call the `updateSlider` method? Set a breakpoint in the method and see in the debugger if the method gets called from somewhere unexpected (a CoreAudio thread ?).

Comment: No nothing unexpected about the call in the debugger

Comment: what does the rest of your code look like?  are you perhaps in some kind of a while(music_not_done) loop where you're not returning and letting messages get processed?  if you're not using a timer for your slider updates, that might be your problem.

Comment: I'm thinking that must be it seams like the main thread is being blocked but only this slider is affected, The playing code is hidden from me in a library and there must be some thread going on somewhere or the "just leaking" messages wouldn't be there.  Or could this be for another reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting updates on another thread and then calling into UIKit on that thread.

Try doing a performSelectorOnMainThread with a new method that does the update (maybe taking an NSNumber object).

Comment: Still leaks the object being passed into the perform Selector tho

Answer (score 0):

Are you retaining a reference to the UISlider? If not, you could be calling -setValue:animated: on a nil reference. Objective-C will allow this, without actually performing the method.

This could potentially explain why you are getting the correct float value passed into the function, but are not getting any updates...

Set a breakpoint as suggested, and make sure that the UISlider reference is not nil.

If not, try posting some code so that we can take a look.

Let us know how it goes,

Tom

Comment: No the slider is there... and I have added

NSLog(@" %f",timeIndexSlider.value);

after the call and the value is correct!... just not visually changing the display.